# How do you work around FirstOrDefault for EF Database models to get all results in ASP.NET MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out what I can use instead of `FirstOrDefault` when trying to get a list of results from an EF database in one of my controller actions.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is whenever a work order is deleted, it loop through a `ProductOrders` table and edit the `Quantity Available` and `Quantity on Hold` amounts for all the records matching the `ProductID`'s from that Order #, then delete the products from order.

My current controller action works perfectly deleting the the order, then deleting the products in `ProductOrders` with the same `orderID`, but the editing part I can only get it to edit the first product before deleting because of the `FirstOrDefault`. If I remove it, then I get an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable to MyProject.Models.ProductOrders

I'm still a newbie when it comes to this stuff and still don't know the ins and outs of querying and making lists.

If I just want to do the product orders and was on the product orders page, this is simple and I wouldn't have this issue, but it's related to my work orders page when an order is deleted. So the id parameter passed is for the work order and not the product order.

For example, if I simply want to delete a product from an order and not an entire work order, in my controller action I can just do:

```
ProductOrder productOrder = db.ProductOrders.Find(id);

foreach (var item in db.ProductOrders.Where(x => x.ProductID == productOrder.ProductID).ToList())
{
    item.Qty_Available = available; //my specified value
    item.Qty_On_Hold = hold; //my specified value

    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

and this will edit all the items that have that `orderID` value, but if I do that in the work order controller, the id parameter is for that model and the `.Find(id)` doesn't get the value I need.

So I did a variable to get the list and it works fine, but I have to use `FirstOrDefault` to be able to link it to the product orders. So here is my current code that does everything I want it to do except for editing all the products within the order instead of just the first record from the `FirstOrDefault`...

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    WorkOrders workOrders = db.WorkOrders.Find(id);        
    var prod = db.ProductOrders.Where(p => p.OrderID == id);

    ProductOrder productOrder = prod.FirstOrDefault();

    var diff = productOrder.Qty_Ordered.Value - productOrder.Qty_Returned.Value;
    var available = productOrder.Qty_Available.Value + diff;
    var hold = productOrder.Qty_On_Hold.Value - diff;

    foreach (var item in db.ProductOrders.Where(x => x.ProductID == productOrder.ProductID).ToList())
    {
        item.Qty_Available = available;
        item.Qty_On_Hold = hold;

        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
        
    db.ProductOrders.RemoveRange(prod);
    db.WorkOrders.Remove(workOrders);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ViewOrders");
}
```

Any help on how to get around this issue would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck for a couple days now and ready to beat my head against the wall.

Most of the examples I've found on how to get all results instead of having to use `FirstOrDefault` have not been applicable to my scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: An `IQueryable` represents a query.  In order to use a queryable, you need to _materialize_ it into query results (which causes the query to be sent to the database and the results sent back).  You can use `.Find`,  `.First`, `.FirstOrDefault`, `.ToList` (etc, plus their `async` cousins) to do this.  In your code, you get work orders, then you get the first matching product order.  If you want more than one product order, you can do what you do later (where you get a list of product orders by calling `.ToList`).  But, if you do this, you won't be able to do your onsie calculations (for `diff`)

Comment: Looks like ProductOrders is a junction table so it should include the Order and Product objects. If you include both Orders and Products in your var prod query with a .ToListAsync() you should be able to loop through that list and update and delete the two objects. (ie: var prod = db.ProductsOrders.Include(i => i.Orders).ThenInclude(i => i.Products).Where(w => w.OrderID == id).ToListAsync();)

Comment: @Flydog57 so if I want more than one product order, how do I accomplish that? Cuz most orders have more than one product placed with an order. So I definitely need it to loop through all the product orders. The problem I have with the .ToList part in my code is that I need it to loop through all the product orders where the ProductID matches the productID's from the products placed on the order # being deleted. I can't figure out how to get the productOrder.ProductID part on (x => x.ProductID == productOrder.ProductID).ToList()) to be anything else other than FirstOrDefault.

Comment: This is probably a really dumb question so I apologize in advance @GHDevOps lol, but what is a junction table? This is an EF Database table, is that the same thing pretty much? My work orders table is the primary key (OrderID), and the product orders table is the foreign key. I'll definitely try what you recommended and see if it works.

Comment: It's a many-to-many table. From your description I think your table structure is wrong. The Northwind db is basically what you're doing. Check out the orders details table in the illustration: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/sample-data/northwind/#:~:text=The%20Northwind%20database%20is%20a,of%20database%20products%20for%20decades.

Comment: @GHDevOps yeah my structure is very similar to the Northwind database. I initially used Northwind as a guide when I got started and set up several tables with many-to-many relationships. I did however cut out the order details table cuz at the time I didn't think it was necessary but realize now I probably shouldn't have done that. Up until now I haven't had any issues at all with the structuring.

Comment: I would never suggest delete a record. You mark it as deleted, never remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            WorkOrders workOrders = db.WorkOrders.Find(id);
            var prod = db.ProductOrders.Where(p => p.OrderID == id);
            foreach (var po in prod.ToList())
            {
                var diff = po.Qty_Ordered.Value - productOrder.Qty_Returned.Value;
                var available = po.Qty_Available.Value + diff;
                var hold = po.Qty_On_Hold.Value - diff;

                foreach (var item in db.ProductOrders.Where(x => x.ProductID == po.ProductID))
                {
                    item.Qty_Available = available;
                    item.Qty_On_Hold = hold;
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
        
            }
            db.ProductOrders.RemoveRange(workOrders.ProductOrders);
            db.WorkOrders.Remove(workOrders);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ViewOrders");
        }
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me the same error message that I couldn't implicitly convert System.Linq.IQueryable to MyProject.Models.WorkOrders on the first line "WorkOrders workOrders = .......ToList()".

Comment: @KipM. Can you try changing that to: WorkOrders workOrders = db.WorkOrders.Where(p => p.OrderID == id).Include(x => x.ProductOrder).AsQueryable().ToList();

Comment: I tried that too and it still is giving me an error message only this time it says: " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.Models.WorkOrders>' to 'MyProject.Models.WorkOrders' "

Comment: You can use var or the type on the declaration: List<MyProject.Models.WorkOrders> workOrders =

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        WorkOrders workOrders = db.WorkOrders.Find(id);
        var prod = db.ProductOrders.Where(p => p.OrderID == id);                            

        foreach (var po in prod.ToList())
        {
            var diff = po.Qty_Ordered.Value - po.Qty_Returned.Value;
            var available = po.Qty_Available.Value + diff;
            var hold = po.Qty_On_Hold.Value - diff;

            foreach(var item in db.ProductOrders.Where(p => p.ProductID == po.ProductID).ToList())
            {
                item.Qty_Available = available;
                item.Qty_On_Hold = hold;
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
          
        }            
        db.ProductOrders.RemoveRange(prod);
        db.WorkOrders.Remove(workOrders);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ViewOrders");
    }
```

So I FINALLY got it working correctly! @wakasupi from your recommendation the extra foreach statement is what made the difference. I kept the workorders query and the var prod the same as my original code, but adding the extra foreach statement for the prod list allowed me to use that full query list instead of having to use firstordefault. Thank you all so much for the help, I've been stuck on this for around a week and was starting to get very irritated that I couldn't figure it out.